# Como puedo crear un arreglo de objetos con propiedades que obtengan valores de variables reactivas?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vue3

Un contexto rápido, tengo la siguiente tabla

```
        <table class="table table-hover custom-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Dosis</th>
              <th>Cantidad</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody> 
            <tr v-for="medicamento in medicamentos" :key="medicamento.id">
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="c1" id="" v-model="c1" :value="medicamento.id" /></td> 
              <td>{{ medicamento.nom_producto }}</td>
              <td><input  placeholder="Dosis" v-model="dosis" ></td>
              <td><input placeholder="Cantidad" v-model="cantidad"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

De la cual obtengo el id que contiene el arreglo medicamento, el cual obtengo de una petición hecha con axios, la variable c1 la tengo declarada de esta manera `const c1 = ref([]);` y la envió mediante esta función

```
 const RegistroConsulta = async () => {
    const Consulta = {
      observaciones: observaciones.value,
      id_productosInternos: c1.value,
      peso: peso.value,
      altura: altura.value,
      edad: edad.value,
      id_cita: id_cita.value,
    };
    try {
      console.log("datos",Consulta);
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://web.Backend.com/RegistroConsulta',
        Consulta
      );
      console.log("respuesta",response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

el endpoint va hacia esta función de mi crud

```
    function RegistroConsulta (){
        try {
          $JSONData = file_get_contents("php://input");
          $dataObject = json_decode($JSONData);


        
          $Consulta = new Consultas();
          $Consulta->id_cita = $dataObject->id_cita;
          $Consulta->observaciones_medicas = $dataObject->observaciones; 
          $Consulta->peso_kg = $dataObject->peso; 
          $Consulta->altura_mts = $dataObject->altura;
          $Consulta->edad_meses = $dataObject->edad; 
          $Consulta->save();
      
          foreach($dataObject->id_productosInternos as $item){
            $dc =new Detalle_Consulta();
            $dc-> id_consulta = $Consulta -> id;
            $dc-> id_producto = $item ;
            $dc -> save();
          }
          $r = new Success($Consulta);
          return $r->Send();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $r = new Failure(401, $e->getMessage());
            return $r->Send();

        }
      }
```

Lo que quiero lograr hacer, es no solo mandar el id, si no, mandar también los campos "dosis" y "cantidad" los cuales están definidos en los v-models de mis inputs.

Intente hacer lo siguiente, crear un arreglo de objetos

```
  const obj = ref ([ 
    {
      producto_id: c1.value,
      dosis: dosis.value,
      cantidad: cantidad.value
    }
  ]);
```

El cual tuviese las propiedades que me interesa mandar, en mi crud intento recorrer de la siguiente manera (los modelos de mis tablas y mis tablas, ya tienen los campos los cuales intento llenar en el método)

```
    function RegistroConsulta (){
        try {
          $JSONData = file_get_contents("php://input");
          $dataObject = json_decode($JSONData);


        
          $Consulta = new Consultas();
          $Consulta->id_cita = $dataObject->id_cita;
          $Consulta->observaciones_medicas = $dataObject->observaciones; 
          $Consulta->peso_kg = $dataObject->peso; 
          $Consulta->altura_mts = $dataObject->altura;
          $Consulta->edad_meses = $dataObject->edad; 
          $Consulta->save();
      
          foreach($dataObject->id_productosInternos as $item){
            $dc =new Detalle_Consulta();
            $dc-> id_consulta = $Consulta -> id;
            $dc-> id_producto = $item ->producto_id;
            $dc-> dosis = $item -> dosis;
            $dc-> cantidad = $item -> cantidad;
            $dc -> save();
          }
          
          $r = new Success($Consulta);
          return $r->Send();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $r = new Failure(401, $e->getMessage());
            return $r->Send();

        }
      }
```

Solo que al intentar hacer, lo que hice, me salta error en la terminal del navegador

```
{
    "status": 401,
    "msg": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`consultasveterinaria`.`detalle_consulta`, CONSTRAINT `detalle_consulta_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_producto`) REFERENCES `productos_internos` (`id`))"
}
```

Verifique la estructura de mis tablas (consultas y detalle_consulta) y la relación de las fk esta bien, ya que al poner el valor de las propiedades del objeto, manualmente, la inserción se hace sin problemas.

Pido disculpas si observan malas practicas, o si escribí mucho texto, soy nuevo en esto y realmente quiero aprender, cualquier sugerencia se tomara en cuenta.

Comment: Creo que lo que el error te dice, es que el valor de `id_producto` no existe en la tabla `productos_internos`

Comment: Lo verifique y mis campos si existen.
Si yo defino manualmente los valores de las propiedades del objeto que intento mandar, se hace la inserción perfectamente.